# How to sum values of multiple columns against multiple columns of the same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of surgeries and their complications with True and False values. I need to know how many times each complication occurs to each surgery. Each row represents a patient. The dataframe looks like this:

```
surgery_1 surgery_2 Surgery_3 complication_1  complication_2 complication_3
True        False     True       True              True         False
False       False     False      False             False        False
True        False     False      True              False        True
```

I want to have a dataframe like this:

```
           complication_1    complication_2     complication_3
surgery_1       1                  1                   0
surgery_2       0                  0                   0
surgery_3       1                  0                   1
```

I tried `df.pivot_table` and `df.groupby` but nothing helps me. **Note** that I'm not interested in how much the surgeries are. I just need to know how many times each complication occurs to each surgery

Comment: When a patient did more than one surgery, how can you tell which complication to which surgery? Or is it for all of them? If so, in the result dataframe you should have 2 in (surgery_1, complication_1) or am I missing something?

Comment: can you put some more data as current data having some ambiguity?

Comment: please provide more specified data regarding compilations. Do You put complitions data just from a finger or there is a function implemented which calculates, whether there is 1 or 0?  We would like to know the logic

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, each row represents an operation performed on a patient. In the operation multiple surgeries might be performed.

Step 1 is to unpivot the DataFrame in order to have each row represent a surgery as this going to be the key of the new DataFrame

```
In [58]: df2 = pd.wide_to_long(df, 'surgery_', ['complication_1', 'complication_2', 'complication_3'], 'surgery_id').reset_index()
Out[58]: 
   complication_1  complication_2  complication_3  surgery_id  surgery_
0            True            True           False           1      True
1            True            True           False           2     False
2            True            True           False           3      True
3           False           False           False           1     False
4           False           False           False           2     False
5           False           False           False           3     False
6            True           False            True           1      True
7            True           False            True           2     False
8            True           False            True           3     False
```

Now you have a row for each surgery and each patient. However not all surgeries are performed on all patients. This is given in remaining value column `'surgery_'`.
Step 2 is to filter so we are only left with the rows where a surgery was actually performed

```
In [64]: df3 = df2.query('surgery_ == True').drop('surgery_', axis=1)
Out[64]: 
   complication_1  complication_2  complication_3  surgery_id
0            True            True           False           1
2            True            True           False           3
6            True           False            True           1
```

Step 3 is then straightforward: `groupby`, `sum` and reindex because there is no entry for `'surgery_2'`

```
In [67]: df2.groupby('surgery_id').sum().reindex([1,2,3], fill_value=0)
Out[67]: 
            complication_1  complication_2  complication_3
surgery_id                                                
1                        2               1               1
2                        0               0               0
3                        1               1               0
```

This differs significantly from you desired output, but frankly I have no idea what you could want other than this ;)